# Unable to convert Epoch value to Human readable date format python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert Epoch value `-2208988800000` using Python version 3.

I have tried online tool to convert https://www.epochconverter.com/ so there I am getting output as 1/Jan/1900.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-2208988800000 / 1000).strftime('%c')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError
Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-15-abaf34dc5003> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-2208988800000 / 1000).strftime('%c')

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromtimestamp` behaviour is dependant on platform. I'm on Windows 10 and negative values are unsupported.

Exerpt from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

> fromtimestamp() may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the range of values supported by the platform C localtime() or gmtime() functions. It’s common for this to be restricted to years in 1970 through 2038.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt.fromtimestamp(-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue; I am using `Python 3.6` on `Ubuntu 18.04` and get this output (might be slightly different because of my timezone):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-2208988800000 / 1000).strftime('%c')
'Sun Dec 31 20:09:20 1899'
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(-2208988800000 / 1000)
datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 31, 20, 9, 20)
```

And using the converter you mentioned in the question, this seems correct:

[image: screenshot]

---

The [`fromtimestamp()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) say that any `OSError` comes from [`time.localtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime).

Comment: Hi Ralf,

 I have tried your approach, But I am getting the same error, 
 I am using Jupyter Notebook with version 3.4 on Windows environment.

Comment: User @Artog mentions in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57728369/9225671) that negative timestamps might not be allowed on Windows